# Display HTML table from SQL DB in custom order

Tags: php, sql

I have created this table with a sql query that looks like this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 5050goosedown");

echo "<table border='0' width='975'>
<tr>
<th width='12.5%'>name:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>width:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>height:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>fill:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>our fill:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>old price:</th>
<th width='12.5%'>price:</th>
</tr>";

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F5F5F5'>";
  if($i%2 == 0){
      echo "<tr bgcolor='#E5E5E5'>";
  }
  $i++;

  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['width'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['height'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['normal_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['our_fill'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['old_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo '<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF><form method="post" action=""><input type="hidden" name="goosedown_id" value="'.$row['goosedown_id'].'" /><input type="submit" name="sumbit" value="Delete" /></form></td>';
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I was wondering what would be the best way to go about displaying the items in the table in a specific order because at the moment is is displaying in alphabetical order. However, I would like it to display in a order of size, *i.e*., single, super single, queen, king, super king…

I just dont know how to attempt this. Do you think maybe I need another entry in the database?

this is what the table looks like.. as you can see there is a section where people can enter their own values

[image]

mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `5050goosedown` (
    `goosedown_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',  
    `width` int(8),
    `height` int(8),
    `normal_fill` int(8),
    `our_fill` int(8),
    `old_price` DECIMAL(3,2),
    `price` DECIMAL(3,2), 
    PRIMARY KEY  (`goosedown_id`)
    ) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

Comment: is there any size column in table??

Comment: Are you talking about the ability to dynamically sort the results after they've been served to the user?  Or are you talking sorting them initially?  If the latter, you can do that by means of "ORDER BY" within your select statement.

Comment: Would `ORDER BY width` be good enough for that?  You don't actually explain what the fields mean, so we can't tell you what fields you do or don't need, can or can't use.

Comment: yea sorry I forgot to add that the user can add their own values to the table.. its a sort of price list for a website for my mum..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However I would like it to display in a order of size, i.e., single,
>   super single, queen, king, super king…

Then try this:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE Size
    WHEN 'sigle' THEN 0 
    WHEN 'super' THEN 1
    WHEN 'single' THEN 2
    WHEN 'queen' THEN 3
    ...
  END , Name
```

Comment: I should have said.. their is a section I have enaled for them to enter new values.. so I will not always know the what values will be entered.. I am adding an image to my question so you get a better idea of what Im doing

Comment: @HurkNburkS - So you have these values stored in `name` columns right? But where are the values in the order you mentioned in your question `single, super single, queen, king, super king` are stored with that order? Are they stored somewhere else in the order you want? Or where did you get that order if you don't need to write it hardcoded?

Comment: I have added a screen shot of the table in question. I am woundering if I should add something to my db that allows you to set the row you want your entry to appear in.. just im not sure how else to do this if im allowing the user to enter values in later on...

Comment: Do you have a seperate table with your sizes which is then joined by ID? If you have a facility to add new sizes, I would also add an option to choose the sort order of the sizes (as a number) then just sort by that.  This also means you can change the sort in the DB without touching code.

Comment: @HurkNburkS - you can make a new table for that with the values in the order you want to sort them with then `JOIN` that table with your original table to get the order you wish [**here is a demo for this**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81611/display-html-table-from-sql-db-in-custom-order)

Comment: okay im checking out ur answer.. i wwill be a minute or two still new to php... also if you look at my updated question i have my table sql.. if that helps

Comment: @HurkNburkS - Yes, I saw it and this what I used to create the same table in the demo

Comment: okay thanks heaps Mahmoud.. im going to implement this now thank!!